# convert text column into JSON formt

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, npm

We have a resource bundle/properties in the following format :

```
[tag1]
server1
server2
[tag2]
server3
server4
[tag3]
server5
server6
[No Software Installed]
server7
[tag2]
server8
[tag5]
server9
[tag1]
server10
server11
[tag3]
server12
server13
server14
server15
[tag6]
server16
server17
```

we need this to be converted into a JSON format such as this:

```
[
["tag1","server1,server2"],
["tag2","server3,server4"],
["tag3","server5,server6"],
["No Software Installed","server7"],
["tag2","server8"],
["tag5","server9"],
["tag1","server10,server11"],
["tag3","server12,server13,server14,server15"],
["tag6","server16,server17"]
]
```

Are there any existing tools to carry our such transformation ?

Comment: This is really close to the `ini` format. Without writing something custom I don't know if you can get to where you want to be. an [ini parser](https://github.com/npm/ini) could be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

you could do this with regex, something like this would work

```js
var regex = /^\[.*\]$/gm;
var input = `[tag1]
server1
server2
[tag2]
server3
server4
[tag3]
server5
server6
[No Software Installed]
server7
[tag2]
server8
[tag5]
server9
[tag1]
server10
server11
[tag3]
server12
server13
server14
server15
[tag6]
server16
server17`;

//use regex to get the keys and values
var keys = input.match(regex);
var values = input.split(regex);
values.shift() //remove the first entry, it will be empty

//iterate over the keys and build the output
var output = [];
for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
  var key = keys[i]
      .replace(/(\[|\])/g, '');
  var valuesArray = values[i]
      .split('\n')
      .filter(function(value){return value !== ''});
  output.push([key].concat(valuesArray));
}

$('#json').text(JSON.stringify(output))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="json"></span>
```

Or

```js
var regex = /^\[.*\]$/gm;
var input = `[tag1]
server1
server2
[tag2]
server3
server4
[tag3]
server5
server6
[No Software Installed]
server7
[tag2]
server8
[tag5]
server9
[tag1]
server10
server11
[tag3]
server12
server13
server14
server15
[tag6]
server16
server17`;

//use regex to get the keys and values
var keys = input.match(regex);
var values = input.split(regex);
values.shift() //remove the first entry, it will be empty

//iterate over the keys and build the output
var output = [];
for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
  var keyValues = {
    key: keys[i]
      .replace(/(\[|\])/g, ''),
    values: values[i]
      .split('\n')
      .filter(function(value){return value !== ''})
  };
  output.push(keyValues);
}

$('#json').text(JSON.stringify(output))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="json"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution for your problem

```
var string = `[tag1]
server1
server2
[tag2]
server3
server4
[tag3]
server5
server6
[No Software Installed]
server7
[tag2]
server8
[tag5]
server9
[tag1]
server10
server11
[tag3]
server12
server13
server14
server15
[tag6]
server16
server17`;
string = string.split('\n'); // split new line
var json = string.reduce(function(o,n){ 
  if(n.charAt(0) === '['){
    o.push([n.slice(1,n.length-1)]);
    return o;
  }
  o[o.length-1].push(n.replace('\n',''))
  return o;
},[])
console.log(JSON.stringify(json,null,' '));
```

Here is a [link for the solution](https://codepen.io/engmzizo/pen/zwWRgM)